# Target object must not be included in a workflow

Tags: reports-api, snapshot

I am trying to create a reporting snapshot. But it shows me error

> "Target object must not be included in a workflow" ......

I even tried to remove all workflows, but this issue persists.
I need some suggestions on what could be the issue.

Comment: Make sure there are no Process Builder jobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_troubleshooting_snapshots.htm&language=en&type=0

According to documentation.

> The custom object in the Target Object field is included in a
>   workflow. Choose a target object that is not included in a workflow.

Comment: but I have removed the object in workflow , then why issue still persists ?